# Using xinput under wine

Tags: wine, games, gamepad

I'm trying to play a game (Legend of Korra) on wine. To my surprise, I didn't encounter any errors (the game is really new, released on the 21st), but it is utterly impossible to play without a gamepad (which I have and it is capable of both xinput and dinput).

AFAIK the kernel supports xinput natively (xpad) and there's also xboxdrv. In wine I have the xinput dll enabled and the game only supports xinput, so that's what I need. I am looking for a solution that fixes the problem and doesn't emulate a keyboard or convert dinput to xinput for wine.

Answer (score 1):

[Here's a fix](http://steamcommunity.com/app/221410/discussions/0/828938354860178892/) And it also uses plain old xinput.

- Download xbox360cemu.v.3.0 (search online - it's widely available)
- Extract it, and copy these files

  ```
  dinput8.dll
  xinput1_3.dll
  xinput9_1_0.dll
  xbox360cemu.ini
  ```

  to the same directory as the game executable within the Steam directory
- install `xboxdrv`
- in a terminal, run

  ```
  sudo xboxdrv --silent --detach-kernel-driver --trigger-as-button --ui-axismap x2=ABS_Z,y2=ABS_RZ --ui-buttonmap A=BTN_B,B=BTN_X,X=BTN_A,TR=BTN_THUMBL,TL=BTN_MODE,GUIDE=BTN_THUMBR
  ```